# Extract accelerometer data from Excel file into MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, loops, accelerometer

I tried searching but came up short on my particular problem. I should mention that I am fairly new to MATLAB, so this may be something obvious but has slipped over my head.

I have an Excel file with accelerometer recordings of 5 events with some space inbetween. These events take place at times (ie rows) I have to specify, such as 120:250, 280:390, 430:943, and so on and so forth.

What I would like to do is to be able to loop through and extract the required data, and have it stored in variables such that each event will have it's own 'section' if you will, and each 'section' would contain it's own set of 'sub-sections' with the X, Y, Z accelerometer data.

My current set up is a manual one, and it looks like this:

```
X1 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','d110:d367');
X2 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','d367:d631');
X3 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','d631:d891');
X4 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','d891:d1134');
X5 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','d1134:d1361');

Y1 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','e110:e367');
Y2 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','e367:e631');
Y3 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','e631:e891');
Y4 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','E891:e1134');
Y5 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','e1134:e1361');

Z1 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','f110:f367');
Z2 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','f367:f631');
Z3 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','f631:f891');
Z4 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','f891:f1134');
Z5 = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','f1134:f1361');
```

So you can see how it is not favorable. The other thing I'd like to do is to eventually use loops for cross correlation against other data sets, but again I'm not sure of the nature of the loops when dealing with 'dynamic' variables or what have you.

Right now the way I am thinking of doing it is that I specify the blocks of rows in a vector or something like that, and loop through for each activity, and then each axis.

Comment: Would you consider reading through it. I happen to write this article myself. But I could not find any other article which would help. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/536002/Read-an-Excel-File-through-Matlab If you still have doubt, leave a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running XLSREAD for every variable won;t be optiomal for performance. This function uses COM interface (at least under Windows) and slow. If the data is not very big and can fit into the memory, it's better to read the whole sheet at once into a temporary variable and then sort the values into variables.

Another advice is not to use X1, X2 etc. You will have problems if you want to use those variable in a loop. If they have different length create a cell array, so they will become X{1}, X{2}, etc.

So, first read the whole file:

```
data = xlsread('location.xlsx','sheet1','D:F');
```

If you data all numeric you will get them in `data` matrix.

The index you can enter manually or get it from the data.

```
index = {120:250, 280:390, 430:943};
for ii = 1:numel(index)
    X{ii} = data(index{ii},1);
    Y{ii} = data(index{ii},2);
    Z{ii} = data(index{ii},3);
end
```

Comment: That works great-- thanks! Now I just have to find out how to print the index{ii} variable name when looping through :p Thanks again.. I've been scratching my head on this one much longer than I should have.